# SQL Summarize by Document Number and detect differences within a column

Tags: sql

I would like to know how it would be possible to summarize/group my data set based on the field Purch Org and for the cases where the values are different within the same column to add a "#multiple" word.

My end result should be one unique line per Doc Number

I am working on Databricks so the solution could be either in SQL or Python

| Doc Number | Purch Org | Material_Group | purchasing_document | Procurement_Class_2 | Procurement_Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 46503991 | DL08XYW | 29130000 (Household wash textil) | Value contract WK | DE (Supplies) | L212 (Domestic & Kitchen Appliance) |
| 46503991 | DL08XYW | 32031600 (Filter (lab)) | Value contract WK | DE (Supplies) | L072 (Laboratory supplies) |
| 46503991 | DL08XYW | 32169000 (Laboratory Supplies) | Value contract WK | D8 (Equipment) | L072 (Laboratory supplies) |

And I want to make it look like the following:

Only one line for each Doc Number, and "#multiple#" where the values are different

| Doc Number | Purch Org | Material_Group | purchasing_document | Procurement_Class_2 | Procurement_Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 46503991 | DL08XYW | #multiple# | Value contract WK | #multiple# | #multiple# |

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
select   [Doc Number]
        ,case when min([Purch Org])            <> max([Purch Org])            then '#multiple#' else min([Purch Org])            end as [Purch Org]
        ,case when min([Material_Group])       <> max([Material_Group])       then '#multiple#' else min([Material_Group])       end as [Material_Group]
        ,case when min([purchasing_document])  <> max([purchasing_document])  then '#multiple#' else min([purchasing_document])  end as [purchasing_document]
        ,case when min([Procurement_Class_2])  <> max([Procurement_Class_2])  then '#multiple#' else min([Procurement_Class_2])  end as [Procurement_Class_2]
        ,case when min([Procurement_Category]) <> max([Procurement_Category]) then '#multiple#' else min([Procurement_Category]) end as [Procurement_Category]

from     t
group by [Doc Number]
```

Another option (cleaner syntax, but the min<>max solution would run better):

```
select   [Doc Number]
        ,case when count(distinct [Purch Org])            > 1   then '#multiple#' else min([Purch Org])            end as [Purch Org]
        ,case when count(distinct [Material_Group])       > 1   then '#multiple#' else min([Material_Group])       end as [Material_Group]
        ,case when count(distinct [purchasing_document])  > 1   then '#multiple#' else min([purchasing_document])  end as [purchasing_document]
        ,case when count(distinct [Procurement_Class_2])  > 1   then '#multiple#' else min([Procurement_Class_2])  end as [Procurement_Class_2]
        ,case when count(distinct [Procurement_Category]) > 1   then '#multiple#' else min([Procurement_Category]) end as [Procurement_Category]

from     t
group by [Doc Number]
```

| Doc Number | Purch Org | Material_Group | purchasing_document | Procurement_Class_2 | Procurement_Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 46503991 | DL08XYW | #multiple# | Value contract WK | #multiple# | #multiple# |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mt4gFQJ8?hide=4)

Comment: I think this solution might be close but not correct because not necessary the first and the last record are the ones that may differ, it could be a missmatch from the 1st line with the 2nd only, and then 3rd, 4th etc...be equal to the first. How could I fix that?

Comment: The solution in fine. Nothing here indicates first or last records. If there are at least two values then the min value would be different than the max value. Theoretically we can use `count distinct`, but this will give a better performance.